# can one class inherit from an other class an have implemented an interface at same time?

Tags: c#, inheritance

somthing like

```
public partial class RegistrationForm : 
          IRegistrationForm, System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

but this example does not work.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what interfaces are there for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, but you do it like this:

```
public partial class RegistrationForm : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IRegistrationForm
```

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, so you put the class you inherit from first, followed by a comma, followed by a comma-delimited list of the interfaces it implements.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely,  a class can inherit from a single base class and implement ***any number*** of interfaces at the same time.

Your example does not work because the one base *class* must be listed first, before all the interfaces...